# Rails multi-instances of one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, file-upload, paperclip

I'm writing simple file upload using Rails 3.1 & Papercip gem.

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :assetable, :polymorphic => true
has_attached_file :data
end
```

How can I load 3 (or more) files in one time. Parent assetable object is already created.

Comment: You may want to clarify your question a bit, to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

be careful with assets name, it will conflict with rails 3.1 asset pipelines...

You should use nested_attributes_for to solve your problem

Comment: Thank u for comment. How can I use nested_attributes_for when parent object is created? In my case there are projects and files. Somebody creates a project and then adds files. There are completely separated tasks.

Comment: in project class, you can add

Comment: ...something like accepts_nested_attributes_for :files, then use cocoon, or watch railscast on nested forms...

Comment: ... and for the assets models (consider using a new name, otherwise your controller assets, action index will conflict) you can use sti model, just add :type field, so you can manage different assets type

Answer (score 0):

You'll only be able to attach one file with paperclip to each instance of Asset as is. If each Asset has one or more files attached, you can put the has_attached_file in another class called Data, or whatever you like, and add a has_many :data to Asset.